# logstash elastic not using source timestamp

Tags: parsing, timestamp, logstash, elastic-stack

Current setup looks like this.

> Spring boot -> log-file.json ( using  [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder)) -> filebeat -> logstash -> elastic

I am able to see logs appearing in elastic search ok.  However its not using the dates provided in the log-file its creating them on the fly.

**json-example**

```
{  
   "@timestamp":"2017-09-08T17:23:38.677+01:00",
   "@version":1,
   "message":"A received request - withtimestanp",
   etc..
```

---

My logstash.conf input filter looks like this.

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    codec => "json"
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts    => [ 'elasticsearch' ]
  }
}
```

If you take a look at the kibana output for the log it has the 9th not the 8th  (when I actually created the log)

[image: kiabana]

Comment: I'm afraid it's [a bug](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-beats/issues/33). There's also [another discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/timestamp-in-log-file-getting-replaced-by-processing-time/54195/4) about it.

Comment: The solution would be to put your timestamp in another field (for example `time`) and use the `mutate` filter with `replace` to change the timestamp field with the value in the `time` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So have now resolved this..  Detail of fix is below.

**logback.xml**

```
<appender name="stash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>info</level>
    </filter>
    <file>/home/rob/projects/scratch/log-tracing-demo/build/logs/tracing-A.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/home/rob/projects/scratch/log-tracing-demo/build/logs/tracing-A.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" >
        <includeContext>false</includeContext>
        <fieldNames>
            <message>msg</message>
        </fieldNames>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

renamed field message to msg as logstash expects different default for message when incoming from beat

**json-file.log**

below is what the sample json output looks like

```
{"@timestamp":"2017-09-11T14:32:47.920+01:00","@version":1,"msg":"Unregistering JMX-exposed beans","logger_name":"org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter","thread_name":"Thread-19","level":"INFO","level_value":20000}
```

**filebeat.yml**

json settings below now handle timestamp issue where it didnt use the time from log file.

Also it moves the json into the root of the json output to logstash.  i.e. its not nested within a beat json event its part of the root.

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /mnt/log/*.log
  json.overwrite_keys: true
  json.keys_under_root: true
  fields_under_root: true

output.logstash:
  hosts: ['logstash:5044']
```

**logstash.conf**

Using the msg rather than message resolves the  JSON parse error, original data now in message field. see here 
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-issue-with-json-input-from-beats-solved/100039

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    rename => {"msg" => "message"}
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts    => [ 'elasticsearch' ]
    user     => 'elastic'
    password => 'changeme'
  }
}
```